# Use of "Align with"

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, relative-pronouns

Would you prefer to define your goals, then find a work which align with it?

The use of "align with" is at right place here?
Or, would you prefer to suggest something else?

Answer (score 4):

I would not use "align" in this sentence, but there is more I would change.

I am not completely sure about what you mean with the first part of your sentence, but since it is grammatical, I will leave it unchanged.

> find a work

Assuming that you mean "the work that someone does for a living", the word you are looking for is **a job**, or maybe **employment**.

> which align with it

You are using align here as a verb, in which case it would take an extra **s**. However, no native speaker would say it like this. You can have a job **in line** with your goals.

"It" is singular, but you are referring to multiple goals, so it should be plural.

So the whole sentence would become

> Would you prefer to set your goals, then find a job in line with them?

To align means "to bring in line", so you could use the verb "align" in a sentence with a similar meaning like this:

> Maybe you want to align your job with your goals.

Comment: I would use "alignment" but only because it is a piece of business jargon used pretty frequently. In non-business contexts it doesn't make as much sense. https://www.google.com/#q=goal+alignment

Answer (score 1):

Your positioning of align is fine, and I am also comfortable with your choice of that word.

But it needs to be *aligns* (3rd person singular) and it should be either *work* (this is an uncountable noun so it loses the indefinite article) or *a job*. Also *goals* is plural so you need the plural pronoun *them* at the end.

Therefore either:

> Would you prefer to define your goals, then find work which aligns
>   with them?

or

> Would you prefer to define your goals, then find a job which aligns
>   with them?